# How to change the orientation in the chart

Tags: java, apache-poi

Is there a way to change the orientation of a chart? I need to put the chart and the table in the same orientation. As you can see, the top element of the chart is the `client 8` and the top element of the table is `client 1`. I need both the be exactly in the same order. How can I do that? What change should I do?

[image]

This is the partial of the code which is generating the chart above.

```
    public ByteArrayInputStream generateFileDetailsWithChart(ClientDataObjectRequest clientDataObjectRequest) {

        ByteArrayOutputStream file = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        try{
            try(XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook()){
                XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(clientDataObjectRequest.getMetricName());
                Font headerFont = workbook.createFont();
                headerFont.setBold(true);
                headerFont.setUnderline(Font.U_SINGLE);
                CellStyle headerCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
                headerCellStyle.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.GREY_40_PERCENT.getIndex());
                headerCellStyle.setFont(headerFont);

                XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
                XSSFClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 15, 15 + clientDataObjectRequest.getCompanyChartData().size());

                Row headerRow = sheet.createRow(anchor.getRow2() + 1);
                headerRow.createCell(0).setCellValue(Constants.CLIENT_NAME);
                headerRow.createCell(1).setCellValue("Value ("+clientDataObjectRequest.getDataFormatCodeValue()+")");

                for (int i = 0; i < headerRow.getLastCellNum(); i++) {
                    headerRow.getCell(i).setCellStyle(headerCellStyle);
                }

                CellStyle rowCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();

                if (clientDataObjectRequest.getDataFormatCodeValue().equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.DATA_FORMAT_PERCENTAGE)) {
                    rowCellStyle.setDataFormat(workbook.createDataFormat().getFormat("0.00%"));
                    for (int i = 0; i < clientDataObjectRequest.getCompanyChartData().size(); i++) {
                        Row row = sheet.createRow(anchor.getRow2() + 2 + i);
                        row.createCell(0).setCellValue(clientDataObjectRequest.getCompanyChartData().get(i).getClientName());
                        row.createCell(1).setCellValue(clientDataObjectRequest.getCompanyChartData().get(i).getValue()/100);
                        //rowCellStyle.setDataFormat(HSSFDataFormat.getBuiltinFormat("#,##0.00%"));
                        row.getCell(1).setCellStyle(rowCellStyle);
                    }
                }

                if (clientDataObjectRequest.getDataFormatCodeValue().equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.DATA_FORMAT_CURRENCY)) {
                    rowCellStyle.setDataFormat(workbook.createDataFormat().getFormat("$0.00"));
                    for (int i = 0; i < clientDataObjectRequest.getCompanyChartData().size(); i++) {
                        Row row = sheet.createRow(anchor.getRow2() + 2 + i);
                        row.createCell(0).setCellValue(clientDataObjectRequest.getCompanyChartData().get(i).getClientName());
                        row.createCell(1).setCellValue(clientDataObjectRequest.getCompanyChartData().get(i).getValue());
                        row.getCell(1).setCellStyle(rowCellStyle);
                    }
                }

                XSSFChart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);
                chart.setTitleText(clientDataObjectRequest.getMetricName());
                chart.getCTChart().getTitle().getTx().getRich().getPArray(0).getRArray(0).getRPr().setSz(2000);
                chart.setTitleOverlay(false);

                //XDDFChartLegend legend = chart.getOrAddLegend();
                //legend.setPosition(LegendPosition.TOP_RIGHT);

                XDDFCategoryAxis bottomAxis = chart.createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
                XDDFTitle title = getOrSetAxisTitle(bottomAxis);
                title.setOverlay(false);
                title.setText(Constants.CLIENT_NAME);
                title.getBody().getParagraph(0).addDefaultRunProperties().setFontSize(12d);


                XDDFValueAxis leftAxis = chart.createValueAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);
                title = getOrSetAxisTitle(leftAxis);
                title.setOverlay(false);
                title.setText("Value ("+clientDataObjectRequest.getDataFormatCodeValue()+")");
                title.getBody().getParagraph(0).addDefaultRunProperties().setFontSize(12d);

                if(clientDataObjectRequest.getDataFormatCodeValue().equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.DATA_FORMAT_PERCENTAGE)) {
                    leftAxis.setMaximum(1.0);
                }
                leftAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.AUTO_ZERO);
                leftAxis.setCrossBetween(AxisCrossBetween.BETWEEN);

                sheet.shiftColumns(0,1,2);
                sheet.autoSizeColumn(2);
                sheet.autoSizeColumn(3);

                XDDFDataSource<String> clientNames = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromStringCellRange(sheet,
                        new CellRangeAddress(anchor.getRow2() + 2,anchor.getRow2() + 1 + clientDataObjectRequest.getCompanyChartData().size(),2,2));

                XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> values = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(sheet,
                        new CellRangeAddress(anchor.getRow2() + 2,anchor.getRow2() + 1 + clientDataObjectRequest.getCompanyChartData().size(),3,3));

                XDDFChartData data = chart.createData(ChartTypes.BAR, bottomAxis, leftAxis);
                XDDFChartData.Series series = data.addSeries(clientNames, values);
                series.setTitle(clientDataObjectRequest.getMetricName(), null);

                setDataLabels(series,7,true); // pos 7 = INT_OUT_END, showVal = true

                chart.plot(data);

                XDDFBarChartData bar = (XDDFBarChartData) data;
                bar.setBarDirection(BarDirection.BAR);

                solidFillSeries(data, 0, PresetColor.BLUE);

                Row bottomRow = sheet.createRow(anchor.getRow2() + clientDataObjectRequest.getCompanyChartData().size() + 3);
                bottomRow.createCell(0).setCellValue(Constants.COPYRIGHT_FOOTER);

                workbook.write(file);
            }
        } catch (Exception e){

        }

        return new ByteArrayInputStream(file.toByteArray());
    }
```

And this is the body which my controller is receiving.

```
{
    "metricName":"Turnover Rate",
    "dataFormatCodeValue": "currency",
    "clientDataRequest":[
       {
          "clientName":"client 1",
          "value":"1"
       },
       {
          "clientName":"client 2",
          "value":"2"
       },
       {
          "clientName":"client 3",
          "value":"3"
       },
       {
          "clientName":"client 4",
          "value":"4"
       },
       {
          "clientName":"client 5555555",
          "value":"5"
       },
       {
          "clientName":"client 6",
          "value":"6"
       },
       {
          "clientName":"client 7",
          "value":"7"
       },
       {
          "clientName":"client 8",
          "value":"8.5"
       }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I tried adding ```bar.getCategoryAxis().setOrientation(AxisOrientation.MAX_MIN);``` but the value axis went to the top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default orientation of a y-axis in a chart is bottom-up. On bottom, where x-axis crosses, is min and on top is max. That is what you have.

This can be changed using [XDDFChartAxis.setOrientation](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/5.0/org/apache/poi/xddf/usermodel/chart/XDDFChartAxis.html#setOrientation-org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.AxisOrientation-) -> [AxisOrientation.MAX_MIN](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/5.0/org/apache/poi/xddf/usermodel/chart/AxisOrientation.html#MAX_MIN). In your case:

```
...
XDDFCategoryAxis bottomAxis = ...
...
bottomAxis.setOrientation(AxisOrientation.MAX_MIN);
...
```

But you set `leftAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.AUTO_ZERO);`. So, because of min (zero) is at top now, `AxisCrosses.AUTO_ZERO` is at top now also. So you need also setting:

```
...
XDDFValueAxis leftAxis = ...
...
leftAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.MAX);
...
```